# Trying to animate/flip deck of cards using css3 and jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions

I have created a deck of cards using javascript/html/css - I am playing around with css animations to deal cards, flip them, etc.  Here is the site http://dalydd.com/projects/deckofcards.html (please view in chrome as I'm only using webkit prefixes)

If you hit the dealcards button it deals cards to two different sections - one is for the (computer player) the other is for the individual player) when the animation deal is finished I am trying to flip the cards for the player part to show the actual cards instead of the back of the card or the back div here is my html and css

```
 <section class="wrapper" style="top: 1px; left: 1px; z-index: 1;"><div class="clubs       eight" data-value="8">eight of clubs<span>8</span></div><div class="back"></div></section>
```

each section represents one card there are two divs within each section one for the card cover and one for the actual card face

Here is the css

```
 #deck section.wrapper.player.flip {
 -webkit-perspective:500;
 -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
 -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
 -webkit-transition: all 1.0s linear;
  }
```

I'm almost there I want it to work like you see here http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/flip/

any help is appreciated as I am pretty new to css animations but see a lot of potential when working with js.

Comment: What is your question specifically?

Comment: how to flip the cards correctly at the end of the animation

Comment: Here is a tutorial - http://www.tommaitland.net/2012/05/how-to-css3-3d-flip-effects/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this involves changing the css -webkit-transition of the parent if it exists - this can get very tricky if you animating multiple properties including parents beforehand.  I have seen only basic examples and tutorials on css 3 animations but nothing quite real world yet.  I'm hoping using css transitions and animations with modernizer can create something all developers can use.  no one has explained this quite yet but I'm not sure what properties of css 3 transitions precede over others - it will be a whole new world to explore.

if you check my site again http://dalydd.com/projects/deckofcards.html it should be working now - the element I am animating was inheriting css properties from a previous animation I did on it's wrapper so I added the style to the parent and the one I'm animating and I wrote out each css property instead of using shorthand

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
-webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
-webkit-transform: rotateX(1deg);
```

Comment: Site is down... do you still have a copy?

Comment: http://ginrummy.surge.sh/ also you can see the code here https://github.com/jdaly13/ginrummy